# How to rename a file while downloading using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, file, download

I am trying to download a receipt file using selenium , every time i download the system is giving random number as name for the file downloading. Is it possible to change the file name while downloading?
[please see the number file name generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pquzd.png)

is it possible to change the file name while saving . please help. thanks

Comment: Name of the file is generated by server. You can 'download as' (not sure if possible using selenium) ot just rename the file after download is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you use the below hack:
First set the default download folder path and then rename the file inside that folder to whatever you need to.

**1) First you need to set the path of the download folder to a specific folder using chromeoption capabilities.**
**Sample code:**

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/downloads/";
    System.out.println("Chrome Download path set to: " + downloadFilepath);
    File downloadtoFolder = new File(downloadFilepath);
    if (!downloadtoFolder.exists()) {
        downloadtoFolder.mkdir();
    }

    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    //This will set the path of the download folder
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.cookies", 1);

    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**2) Below Method will rename file bases on two arguments a) new file name and b) directory path**

**Sample code:**

```
private static void fileRename(String newFileName, String folder) {
        File file = new File(folder);
        System.out.println("Reading this " + file.toString());
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            List<File> filelist = Arrays.asList(files);
            filelist.forEach(f -> {
                System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                String newName = folder + newFileName;
                System.out.println(newName);
                boolean isRenamed = f.renameTo(new File(newName));
                if (isRenamed)
                    System.out.println(String.format("Renamed this file %s to  %s", f.getName(), newName));
                else
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s file is not renamed to %s", f.getName(), newName));

            });

        }
```